# F# compilation hangs in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, f#

I've got a solution containing a mixture of C# and F# projects (it's a Silverlight app). When I attempt to compile it in Visual Studio 2010 SP1, the build process hangs on one of the F# projects. If I remove that project, it hangs on a different F# project.

The F# compiler (`fsc.exe`) isn't running, and I can't find any likely-looking process to kill (other than `devenv.exe`).

It compiles fine on the command line, using MSBuild. It compiles fine in VS11 beta. We can't (yet) migrate the solution to VS11.

This occurs on my PC, and one other PC. None of the other team members have this problem.

Has anyone seen this behaviour before? How do I go about debugging this?

Comment: Solution/project files that have been converted by VS 11 are still usable in VS 2010. As long as the builds you ship to customers are done on a machine without .NET 4.5 on it, there's no real downside to moving to VS 11 on the machines with this issue.

Comment: F# projects are not compatible in VS11 Beta.

Comment: @Brian - Really? I mean, you'd be in a position to know, I'm just surprised because I've got a solution with several F# (and C#) projects that loads and compiles just fine in both VS 2010 and VS 11. I'm aware that [NuGet doesn't work very well with F# projects](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/2149) in VS 11, but I hadn't noticed any other issues.

Comment: It is possible to have projects that work in both versions, but there are some incompatibilities in edge cases and the Beta had some bugs in the upgrader.  If it's working for you, great, but don't have the expectation that it's an 'it just works' thing in general.

Comment: Make sure you have SP1 installed for VS2010. We had one guy on the team who hadn't installed it yet and couldn't handle projects touched by VS11 Beta. However, it doesn't sound like that is the issue, but maybe something to check.

Comment: Er, this question's not about VS11...

Answer (score 3):

It may be useful to go to Tools\Options\Projects&Solutions\Build&Run and change MSBuild output verbosity to 'diagnostic' and then check the output window to see exactly where things are getting hung, that may help diagnose.